# How to fully cover conditionals while testing code (eg. PHP and xdebug)

Tags: php, phpunit, code-coverage, xdebug

Some time ago I have started writing tests in PHPUnit (v. 9). It's great and amazing but:

How I can properly cover conditionals?

I will give some examples where result is correct and expected, and where I see problems. Here it is:

> Please note that code below is only the sample.
>
> I know that when I pass `true` to `if` statement there will be no chance to go to other branch of code. It's only the example as plain as possible.

Situation where problem does not exits:

```
if (true) {
    return 'true';//here is covered
}
return 'false';//here is not covered
```

And this is ok, however below:

```
return (true) ? 'true' : 'false';
```

Whole line is treated as covered, but is obvious that false will never be returned.

So. What am I doing bad?

Only solution is not to use ternary operator? Its very short syntax, but error-prone because of lack of (real / false) information about coverage. :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default view in PHP Unit is indeed **line coverage**, and hence, as you indicate can't distinguish both branches in the single line ternary case.

However, more recently PHPUnit also has [branch and path coverage](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.5/code-coverage-analysis.html#software-metrics-for-code-coverage). [image: PHP Unit output]

It shows this in the output left of "Lines". In order to see which branches are missing, you can hover over a line in the source view that is yellow, and it will tell you that (in my example) only 3 out of 4 possible paths have been followed.

[image: branches view]

The author of this feature also wrote an [extensive explanation on his blog](https://doug.codes/php-code-coverage#branch-coverage).